# How to add a condition in Eloquent query based on related model data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

If you have a query that uses eager loading like this:

```
Brand::with('tags')
  ->where('id', $id)
  ->get();
```

A `brand` can have many `tags`.

I then also have an array of tag ids like this `[2,4]`. How do I add a condition to this query where it returns only those brands whose tags are in the array?

I tried the eager load constraints but that condition is then placed on the `tags` model, not the `Brand`.

I tried this also but it returns an `unknown method` error:

```
public function tagsIn($allTags){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'brand_tags')
        ->whereIn('tags.id', $allTags);
}

Brand::with('tags')
  ->tagsIn('[2,4]')
  ->get();
```

I suspect a possible limitation to getting it to work is the fact that Eloquent makes two separate database calls. But is there a way nevertheless?

Comment: In your query you are first selecting the specific `Brand` with id `$id` and then you want to select the `Brand` with tags given in `$tags` array ? Is it like if the selected brand has the tags given in `$tags` then only return the `brand` else null ?

Comment: @jaysingkar wrong example, sorry. The query is meant to retrieve all brands and their tags, then filter based on the tag ids.

Comment: why don't you use `Tags` as base table to retrieve `Brands` that belongs to tags in array ?

Comment: @jaysingkar not all brands have tags... :/

Comment: ok.. but if i'm understanding correctly you only want the the `Brands` that belongs to tags given in array.. So, if the `Brands` that do not have tags.. we don't need it anyway.. right ?

Comment: Though I'm not sure about eager loading, but you can achieve this using joins.. see my answer if it is of any help.. Though, do have a look on my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::table('Brands')
    ->join('brand_tag','brands.id','=','brand_tag.brand_id')
    ->join('tags','brand_tag.tag_id','=','tags.id')
    ->whereIn('tags.id',$allTags)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I suppose the raw-ish way is needed as Eloquent doesn't have the solution right out the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `DB::table('name')->whereIn('column', array(1, 2, 3))->get();`

Comment: `column` isn't in table `name` but on an eager loaded model

Comment: replace the `column` with your column name `tags`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this package to handle tag. I used it in my projects. [laravel-tagging](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging)

Comment: It's a good package but with some limitations: e.g. a tag can't be in multiple groups. Good investigation is required as not all projects will fit just right.